# $C_4\rtimes C_2$ isn't isomorphic to $C_4\times C_2$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Explain why $C_4\rtimes C_2$ isn't isomorphic to $C_4\times C_2$

---

My first thought was to say that since $C_4\rtimes C_2 \simeq  C_4$ then if $C_4\rtimes C_2\simeq C_4\times C_2 $ we would get $C_4\times C_2 \simeq C_4$ which is a contradiction since $|C_4\times C_2|\neq |C_4|$

Is my answer correct ?

Is there a better way/answer to explain this ?

(I am assuming the exercise means $C_4,C_2$ are the cyclic groups with $4 $ and $2$ elements)

Comment: No, the answer is not correct. Which action is given for the semidirect product? Of course it can be isomorphic to the direct product, when the action is trivial.

Comment: $C_4\rtimes C_2$ is definitely not isomorphic to $C_4$. The first group has order $8$.

Comment: (On the other hand, a non-trivial semi-direct product of Abelian groups is non-Abelian, and a trivial one is, so these can never be isomorphic.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff that i know, but is my answer ok ?

Comment: Pedro already pointed out why it is not correct. The statement after "since" is really wrong.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I missed the first comment of pedro for some reason, my bad

Comment: No problem. There are in fact several semidirect products of $C_4$ and $C_2$, but they are all isomorphic to only two groups, see the duplicate, either to $C_4\times C_2$ or to $D_4$ of order $8$. Of course, these two groups are non-isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is abelian, the other is not (assuming the action defining the semidirect product is not trivial).

**Theorem**: If $\varphi: G\to H$ is a surjective group homomorphism and $G$ is abelian, then $H$ is abelian.

*Proof:* Let $x,y\in H$. Then there exist $a,b\in G$ such that $x=\varphi(a), y=\varphi(b)$, so

$$\begin{align}
xy&=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)\\
&=\varphi(ab)\\
&=\varphi(ba)\\
&=\varphi(b)\varphi(a)\\
&=yx.
\end{align}$$

Hence $H$ is abelian.$\square$